# Interpolation of measured values with Python

Tags: python, interpolation, scatter-plot, measurement

I want to create an efficiency map from measured data in Python. For this purpose I have already tested different interpolation methods. Unfortunately I am not satisfied with the result and would like to ask you for your advice.

I have shown here an example of RBF interpolation, which illustrates my problem well. Between the measured values, the interpolation always falls into a kind of "valley", which is not correct, however. I think that it is difficult for the interpolation to interpolate down to zero on two sides of the plateau.

Here you can find the measuring values (x,y,z) in a matrix:
[Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bMbYJ4JJg5vU4JD_wpXU0EoVUhNt3m4l6tZ2lufzouU/edit?usp=sharing)

And here follows the minimal example:

```
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import pandas as pd 
from scipy.interpolate import RBFInterpolator, RegularGridInterpolator, LinearNDInterpolator, NearestNDInterpolator

 
df = pd.read_csv("Data.csv") 
mat = df.to_numpy()

x = mat[:,0]
y = mat[:,1]
z = mat[:,2]

# 3D-Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})
ax.set_title('Data points')
ax.scatter(x, y, np.transpose(z), marker='o', c='black', s=2)
ax.view_init(30, -115)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')


num_points = 500
xi = np.linspace(min(x),max(x),num_points)
yi = np.linspace(min(y),max(y),num_points)
XI, YI = np.meshgrid(xi, yi) 


# RBFInterpolator
measured_points = np.stack([x.ravel(), y.ravel()], -1)
interpolated_points = np.stack([XI.ravel(), YI.ravel()], -1)
interpolation_rbf = RBFInterpolator(measured_points, z.ravel(), smoothing=0, kernel='linear')
z_rbf = interpolation_rbf(interpolated_points).reshape(num_points, num_points)    
         
# 3D-Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})
ax.set_title('RBFInterpolator')
surf = ax.plot_surface(XI, YI, z_rbf, cmap='jet')   
ax.scatter(x, y, np.transpose(z), marker='o', c='black', s=2)
ax.view_init(30, -115)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')

# LinearNDInterpolator
interp = LinearNDInterpolator(list(zip(x, y)), z)
ZI = interp(XI, YI)

# 3D-Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})
ax.set_title('LinearNDInterpolator')
surf = ax.plot_surface(XI, YI, ZI, cmap='jet')   
ax.scatter(x, y, np.transpose(z), marker='o', c='black', s=2)
ax.view_init(30, -115)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')

# NearestNDInterpolator
interp = NearestNDInterpolator(list(zip(x, y)), z)
ZI = interp(XI, YI)

# 3D-Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})
ax.set_title('NearestNDInterpolator')
surf = ax.plot_surface(XI, YI, ZI, cmap='jet')   
ax.scatter(x, y, np.transpose(z), marker='o', c='black', s=2)
ax.view_init(30, -115)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
```

The measured values and the interpolation can be seen in the following figures.

[Measured Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2tJk.png)

[RBF Interpolation of Measured Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38943.png)

Edit:
Now I have added the LinearNDInterpolator and the NearestNDInterpolator. The LinearNDInterpolator comes closer to my ideas, but it also creates some valleys.
[LinearNDInterpolator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fc2qp.png)

On the following picture you can see how the map should normally look like.
[Efficiency Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBxTM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The [radial basis functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function) used by [RBFInterpolator()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RBFInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.RBFInterpolator) assumes the value depends only on distance from a given point - either the origin or the center of the sample matrix.  For your source data, you've got a bunch of samples with zero on the x and y axes.  RBFInterpolator is thus trying to go close to zero for distances corresponding to axes' samples, even when the same distance shows up in the middle of a bunch of values with non-zero distance.  That is, by choosing RBFInterpolator, you've declared the result should look like ripples on a pond moving out from a single point.

In general, choice of interpolation algorithm reflects assumptions about the underlying structure of the data. The choice of basis (axes) is also potentially important. If you want something that "should just be smooth and continuous in the coordinates you're using to make the plot" without additional constraints or structure, then linear interpolation or one of the spline options is usually the way to go.  If you have domain knowledge of what the shape should be, independent of measurement, you can build kernels for that - but you haven't stated any such constraints.

Just use linear interpolation unless you have need of specific features for some other interpolation scheme.  In your case, with a regular grid of samples, the [scipy RegularGridInterpolator](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator) should be fine.

If you want smoother curves than what linear interpolation provides, set method to "cubic".  If you also need continuous third-order derivatives in the interpolation, set the method to "quintic".

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation. When using the RegularGridInterpolator I get the error message:
"ValueError: The points in dimension 0 must be strictly ascending or descending".

I have expanded my input post and added the LinearNDInterpolator as well as the NearestNDInterpolator. Also an example how the interpolated area should look like.

Comment: @patrick try sorting the `df` DataFrame by the x & y axes before you convert it to a numpy matrix.

Comment: @ Sarah Messer I don't really understand. How should I sort the values and what should change then? Can you possibly explain it to me?

Comment: You're plotting z vs x & y, right? I don't know what the columns are called in your CSV, so I can't give you exact code, but that's functionally what you're doing? And you eventually set axes x, y, and z for the output. The issue that scipy RegularGridInterpolator is complaining about is that it assumes the input data is sorted by x and y, but that appears to not be the case.  pd.read_csv() builds column names from the CSV and orders them as they are in the file. The column labels get dropped when you call df.to_numpy(), so you should sort the DataFrame df before that.

Comment: To sort the DataFrame, you'll want to call `df.sort_values(by=['x', 'y'], inplace=True)` but replace 'x' and 'y' with the actual names of your columns.  See also https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Comment: I have now done the sorting, but nothing has changed.